# Incompatible types required java.lang.string found java.lang.object

Tags: java, android

I'm following [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) tutorial to be able to implement Google Places API on a search view. I'm getting the following error on this line:

> Incompatible types required java.lang.string found java.lang.object

```
@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}
```

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList resultList = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:gr");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            System.out.println("============================================================");
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Comment: In which statement did the error happened?

Comment: Override
  public String getItem(int index) {
     return resultList.get(index);
  } @OctavianoPutra

Answer (score 3):

The ArrayList `resultList` does not have any type information assigned to it, so it is being treated as an Object. When you take something from this list in `getItem()` you are expecting it to be a String, which is what is causing the error.

You have two options to fix this. Either change the ArrayList to be `ArrayList<String>`, or in getItem() cast the result to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check Your **StackTrace** . You are able to resolve this error because only `datatype` mismatch is being occured. Please embed your **StackTrace** to identify the line where this `Exception` actually came.

### Compile Time Error

**required** `java.lang.string` **found** `java.lang.object` Read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
private ArrayList resultList;
```

to this:

```
private ArrayList<String> resultList;
```

Comment: This brings about an error in this section of code @f1sh : catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;

Comment: You have to change the result type of the function as well: ``public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {``.

Comment: I don't know, it's a malformed url exception which is thrown before the method returns the resultList. Sounds unrelated to me. (return type definitely has to change though...)

Comment: @ewanc this doesnt have anything to do with the exceptions. The compile error only happens in the return statement, the OP just copied way too much code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread that. I thought OP meant this exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getItem() method as following:

```
@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
  return (String)resultList.get(index);
}
```